# Relay to electronic switch change

Tags: mosfet, relay, power-electronics, jfet, spdt

I would like to change relay functionality in electronic switch. As per the concept, relay pole and NC position is short even there is no power applied to it. I need complete exact relay functionality even in power loss condition. Is it possible to implement using JFETs?

Also, in a relay the signal can travel from pole to NC/NO or NC/NO to pole. That means I am bypassing the NC or NO condition as per coil voltage. Is it possible to implement using JFET?

I need more of SPDT switch (pole, NC and NO) configuration even in power loss condition.  Can you please help me with circuit?

Comment: A JFET might work but a lot more details about the specific signals that you are switching are needed. Voltage and current levels, acceptable volt drop levels, acceptable blocking impedance values etc..

Comment: If possible can you please provide me high level circuit. I am least bothered about current level. I am more interested in Signal switching at max voltage of 5V with frequency of 100KHz. I need it in NO and NC configuration.

Comment: No, this isn't how this site works. You need to be more explicit about your requirements. I can tell you that your application sounds like it might suit an analogue switch but that's about it.

Comment: One reason for using a relay is the isolation it provides, you need to specify whether or not this is something you need.

Comment: Its more of analog switch but the thing is analog switch wont work when supply voltage is not provided. I need the same kind of configuration even there is no power applied to the circuit exactly similar to the Relay function. Relay provides isolation to NO and NC pins. I am looking more of same.

Comment: So, use a relay NC contact Or JFET) for the unpowered situation then, when power is applied use the analogue switch for high speed switching.

Comment: A depletion mode FET will be "normally closed" or "on" or "conducting" when there is little or no gate voltage. You could design a circuit around a depletion mode FET that would remain "closed" or "on" even in the even of power supply failure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *depletion*-mode MOSFET for your NC output, and an enhancement-mode MOSFET for your NO output. Enhancement-mode MOSFETs turn on when |Vgs| (the absolute value of Vgs) exceeds a certain threshold. Depletion-mode MOSFETs turn on when |Vgs| is *below* a certain threshold.

Since you don't mention voltage or current levels, I can't recommend a specific one, but take this one just as an example.

https://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/DS100178A(IXTY-TA-TP08N50D2).pdf

You can search for "depletion MOSFET" in Digikey, Farnell, etc.